# How to get data from WordPress Object?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get all user list of a specific category. I use `WP_User_Query()` function for the query and assign its returned value into a variable.When I use `var_dump()` then its show as like http://postimg.org/image/48st2h0jj/. How can I get the role of that user from that object. My code is below ..

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Administrator' ) );
foreach ($user_query as $user) {
   $aa = $user->role;
   echo $aa;   
}
```

But It doesn't work as I want. How can I solve this problem.
Thanks...Anam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long search I find my own solution... At first I have to make object as an array. Then I get the result from that array... here is my own code

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Administrator' ) );
$posts = $user_query->get_results();

foreach ($posts as $user) {
   $aa = $user->roles[0];
   echo $aa;   
}
```

Thanks to all for answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'role' => 'Administrator'
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->role . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

if it's Not Work Than Use This code

```
$administrator_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'role'=>'administrator',
    )
);
$user_query= $administrator_query->get_results();
   foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    echo '<p>' . $user->role . '</p>';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Administrator' ) );
foreach ( $user_query as $user ) {
$value = json_decode(json_encode($user),true);
echo $value['role']."<br>";
}
```

json_decode function will convert it into array format and then we can access them

Comment: Its works.. But... there was some error like http://postimg.org/image/qnmxpc54v/ and my code is http://postimg.org/image/tvrf2dren/